# Does a subtype "inherit" generic interface parameterized with that particular subtype (Java)?

Tags: java, oop, generics, inheritance, interface

I have

```
class Shape implements Comparable <Shape>
```

and

```
class Square extends Shape
```

I wrote a generic method for finding the maximum element within an array:

```
public static <S extends Comparable<S>> S findMax(S[] arr)
{
    //blablabla...
    return maxS;
}
```

These two calls give me no errors and do what they're supposed to:

```
Shape maxShape = findMax(new Shape[]{new Shape(1), new Shape(2), new Shape(3)});
Square maxSquare = findMax(new Square[]{new Square(1), new Square(2), new Square(3)});
```

Therefore, it seems reasonable to me that since `Shape` implements `Comparable<Shape>` and `Square` extends `Shape`, `Square`s should also be comparable, a.k.a. `Square` somehow automatically implements `Comparable<Square>` through inheritance (particularly by inheriting `compareTo(Shape s)`).

However, according to my textbook, this is not the case: here "all we know is that `Square implements Comparable<Shape>`; thus a `Square` IS-A `Comparable<Shape>`, but IS-NOT-A `Comparable<Square>`", and it suggests a better method signature instead:
`public static <S extends Comparable<? super S>>`.

Then why does my `public static <S extends Comparable<S>>` give me no problem?

-----------------------------UPDATE (SOURCE CODE)------------------------------

```
public class Shape implements Comparable<Shape>{
    protected int area;
    public Shape (int i)
    {
        this.area=i;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return area+"";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("Bigger shape: "+findMax(new Shape[] {new Shape(2),new Shape(3)}));
        System.out.println("Bigger square: "+findMax(new Square[] {new Square(2),new Square(3)}));

    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return area;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Shape sh) {
        return Integer.valueOf(area).compareTo(sh.getValue());
    }

    public static <N extends Comparable<N>> N findMax(N[] arr)
    {
        int maxIdx=0;
        for (int i=1; i<arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i].compareTo(arr[maxIdx])>0)
                maxIdx=i;
        return arr[maxIdx];
    }

}

class Square extends Shape
{
    public Square(int i)
    {
        super(i);
    }

    public int compareTo(Shape sh)
    {
        return Integer.valueOf(area%3).compareTo(sh.getValue()%3);
    }
}
```

And the output I get is

```
Bigger shape: 3
Bigger square: 2
```

Lesson learned: the answer to the original question is no. As Tagir Valeev pointed out, it is permissible to call `findMax` on `Square[]` without assignment due to the covariant nature of `Shape[]`.

Comment: You might notice a problem if the implementations of the `compareTo` methods are different.

Comment: Are you sure it's working fine? Where have you defined `findMax()` method? Also which version of JDK? It's giving error for me.

Comment: @Codebender: what error did it give you? I'm using jdk1.8.0_60. I defined the findMax inside Shape (that probably made a big difference! Why didn't didn't think about this before...)

Comment: @YiboYang, this does not make the difference. Please post the complete source code. I don't have 1.8.0_60 installed, but 1.9.0_ea74 gives the same error as 1.8.0_40.

Comment: By the way hopefully you aware that `Collections.max(Arrays.asList(shapes))` does the same.

Comment: At first I was really expecting an error at the call site `findMax(new Square[] {new Square(3),new Square(2)}))`... Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code does not compile. Javac 1.7:

```
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javac.exe" GenericTest.java
GenericTest.java:32: error: method findMax in class GenericTest cannot be applied to given types;
                Square maxSquare = findMax(new Square[]{new Square(1), new Square(2), new Square(3)});
                                   ^
  required: S[]
  found: Square[]
  reason: inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)
    inferred: Square
    bound(s): Comparable<Square>
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Comparable<S> declared in method <S>findMax(S[])
1 error
```

Javac 1.8:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\javac.exe" GenericTest.java
GenericTest.java:32: error: incompatible types: inference variable S has incompatible bounds
                Square maxSquare = findMax(new Square[]{new Square(1), new Square(2), new Square(3)});
                                          ^
    equality constraints: Shape
    upper bounds: Square,Comparable<S>
  where S is a type-variable:
    S extends Comparable<S> declared in method <S>findMax(S[])
1 error
```

ECJ 3.10.2:

```
>java -jar org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.10.2.v20150120-1634.jar -source 1.7 GenericTest.java
----------
1. ERROR in C:\projects\Test\src\GenericTest.java (at line 32)
        Square maxSquare = findMax(new Square[]{new Square(1), new Square(2), new Square(3)});
                           ^^^^^^^
Bound mismatch: The generic method findMax(S[]) of type GenericTest is not applicable for the arguments (GenericTest.Square[]). 
The inferred type GenericTest.Square is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <S extends Comparable<S>>
----------
1 problem (1 error)
```

All compilers produce correct error message as expected. If you declare `findMax` method as `public static <S extends Comparable<? super S>> S findMax(S[] arr)`, then the error message correctly disappears.

**Update** after you posted the complete code the problem becomes clear. The difference is that you don't assign the result of `findMax` to the variable:

```
System.out.println("Bigger shape: "+findMax(new Shape[] {new Shape(1),new Shape(3)}));
System.out.println("Bigger square: "+findMax(new Square[] {new Square(3),new Square(2)}));
```

So in both cases `<S>` is inferred to `Shape` as `Square[]` type IS-A `Shape[]` type.

Comment: I corrected the `compareTo` method in `Shape` (see updated source code), and I observe dynamic binding when calling `findMax` with `Shape[]` and `Square[]`. So that's type erasure at work, correct? Because even though `<S>` is inferred to be `Shape` at compile time, there's nothing to prevent the actual type (`Square`) from being used at runtime...

Comment: @YiboYang, of course the method call is virtual, so `Square.compareTo` will be called. However its parameter is still `Shape` and you are not guaranteed that `Square` will be passed. So if you have additional fields in `Square` which you want to compare, you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks. So what should be the signature of `static <S extends Comparable<? super S>> S findMax(S[] arr)` after type erasure? Should it be `static Comparable findMax(Comparable[] arr)`?

Comment: @YiboYang, yes, exactly.